# Is there a calculation to find what motor is required for a specific propeller?

Tags: motor

So I am going to be running 20x5.5 carbon fibre drone propellers at 10,000 rpm maximum and I cannot find out which motor I need. I have been scouring the web for weeks and I have given up and I am sorry about that. Is there any way to find the right motor? Can you at least tell me how to search for it?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous motor calculators on line that you can use to estimate how much power will be required to reach a particular RPM, and how much thrust that will give.

[eCalc](https://www.ecalc.ch/motorcalc.php) is probably the best known, but there are several. They use standard motor equations and data from testing popular props.

[RCGroups keeps a list of all the calculators](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?606703-e-flight-calculators-%28compilation%29)